# how to loop over multiple registers in linux device tree node?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I implemented a generic driver, in the driver I just want to go over each registered device and do something.
my driver is generic so I don't want to know anything in advance about the devices.

I have some device tree nodes:

```
uart0: uart@1000000 {
    compatible = "generic-driver";
    reg = <0x1000000 0x1000>,<0x1001000 0x1000>,<0x1002000 0x1000>;  
}; 

uart1: uart@2000000 {
    compatible = "generic-driver";
    reg = <0x2000000 0x1000>,<0x2001000 0x1000>,<0x2002000 0x1000>;  
};
```

in the driver I know how to get first offset and size with platform_get_resource, but what if I have multiple ranges?
I saw an option to get it by add reg-names:

```
reg = <0x2000000 0x1000>,<0x2001000 0x1000>,<0x2002000 0x1000>;
reg-names = "uart0_0","urat0_1","uart0_2";
```

so in the driver I can use platform_get_resource_byname, but there I need to know in the driver the regs names in advance - but it'll be no more generic - unwanted!!

so my question is, is there a way to loop over these regs without early information in the driver?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How you are supposed to write a “generic” stuff for different hardware?! You need to know what tho hardware is and what the resources driver is expecting.

Comment: I want to implement a "generic" driver because of it fits my needs. I want ONE driver that will do same work for each registered device.  I don't think you're right.

Comment: There’s no universal or **the** driver. You’re conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the definition for `platform_get_resource` you will find that the last parameter is the resource number. So, for the example you gave resource numbers will range from 0 to 2.

In case you don't know the number of resource then you can run an loop till you get a `NULL` as response to `platform_get_resource`.